# Elementos se concatenan al crearlos en el DOM

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Estoy haciendo un 3 en raya en el que genero una preview creando un elemento temporal que creo y elimino constantemente, pero al jugar varias rondas ese elemento se va concatenando y empieza a superponerse, en la ronda 2 se generan 2 elementos, en la ronda 3 se generan 3, y asi sucesivamente.

Se puede ver el efecto que esto produce con la opacidad

```js
let pointCircle = document.getElementById("circle");
let pointCross = document.getElementById("cross");

let circleImage = document.createElement("img");
circleImage.src = "resources/circle.png";
circleImage.id = "circleImage";

let circleText = document.createElement("span");
circleText.textContent = "0";
circleText.id = "circleText";
circleText.style.fontSize = "64px";
circleText.style.fontFamily = "consolas";

let crossImage = document.createElement("img");
crossImage.src = "resources/cross.png";
crossImage.id = "crossImage";

let crossText = document.createElement("span");
crossText.textContent = "0";
crossText.id = "crossText";
crossText.style.fontSize = "64px";
crossText.style.fontFamily = "consolas";

pointCircle.innerHTML = "";
pointCross.innerHTML = "";

pointCircle.appendChild(circleImage);
pointCircle.appendChild(circleText);
pointCross.appendChild(crossImage);
pointCross.appendChild(crossText);

let cells = document.querySelectorAll(".game-cell");
let isPlayer1turn = Math.round(Math.random());

function start() {
    restartGrid();

    cells.forEach(function (cell) {
        let tempElement = document.createElement("div");

        cell.addEventListener("mouseenter", function () {
            if (cell.style.backgroundImage === "") {
                tempElement.className = "grid-item-before";

                tempElement.style.position = "absolute";
                tempElement.style.width = "75px";
                tempElement.style.height = "75px";
                tempElement.style.backgroundImage = "url(./resources/" + (isPlayer1turn ? "circle" : "cross") + ".png)";
                tempElement.style.backgroundSize = "cover";
                tempElement.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
                tempElement.style.opacity = "0.5";

                cell.appendChild(tempElement);
            }
        });
        cell.addEventListener("mouseleave", function () {
            if (cell.style.backgroundImage === "") {
                cell.removeChild(tempElement);
            }
        });
        cell.addEventListener("click", function () {
            if (cell.style.backgroundImage === "") {
                cell.removeChild(tempElement);
                cell.style.backgroundImage = "url(./resources/" + (isPlayer1turn ? "circle" : "cross") + ".png)";
                cell.className += isPlayer1turn ? " circle" : " cross";

                checkPositions();

                isPlayer1turn = !isPlayer1turn;
            }
        });
    });
}

function checkPositions() {
    let crossMarked = document.querySelectorAll(".cross");
    let circleMarked = document.querySelectorAll(".circle");

    let crossNumbers = [];
    let circleNumbers = [];

    if (isPlayer1turn) {
        getPositions(circleMarked, circleNumbers);
        if (validatePositions(circleNumbers)) {
            resetGame("circle");
        }
    } else {
        getPositions(crossMarked, crossNumbers);
        if (validatePositions(crossNumbers)) {
            resetGame("cross");
        }
    }
}

function getPositions(turn, numbers) {
    turn.forEach(function (item) {
        let idNumber = (item.id).split("-")[1];
        numbers.push(parseInt(idNumber))

    })
}

function validatePositions(arr) {

    const WIN_CONDITIONS = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 7], [1, 5, 9], [2, 5, 8], [3, 5, 7], [3, 6, 9], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9],];

    for (const winCondition of WIN_CONDITIONS) {
        let containsAll = true;
        for (const position of winCondition) {
            if (!arr.includes(position)) {
                containsAll = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (containsAll) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function resetGame(winner) {
    if (winner === "circle") {
        cells.forEach(function (cell) {
            cell.classList.remove("circle", "cross");
            cell.style.backgroundImage = "";

            cell.removeEventListener('mouseenter', event_handler);
            cell.removeEventListener('mouseleave', event_handler);
            cell.removeEventListener('click', event_handler);
        });

        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(254, 63, 63, 0.4)";
        setTimeout(function () {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#f0f0f0";

            let circleText = document.getElementById("circleText");
            console.log(parseInt(circleText.textContent) + 1);
            circleText.textContent = parseInt(circleText.textContent) + 1;
        }, 2000)

        cells.forEach(function (cell) {
            console.log(cell)
            cell.style.backgroundImage = "";
        });

    } else {
        cells.forEach(function (cell) {
            cell.classList.remove("circle", "cross");
            cell.style.backgroundImage = "";

            cell.removeEventListener('mouseenter', event_handler);
            cell.removeEventListener('mouseleave', event_handler);
            cell.removeEventListener('click', event_handler);
        });

        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(76, 208, 250, 0.4)";
        setTimeout(function () {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#f0f0f0";

            let circleText = document.getElementById("crossText");
            console.log(parseInt(circleText.textContent) + 1);
            circleText.textContent = parseInt(circleText.textContent) + 1;
        }, 2000)
    }

    function event_handler(event) {
    }

    //restartGrid();
    start();
}

function restartGrid() {
    cells.forEach(function (cell) {
        let itemsBefore = cell.querySelectorAll(".grid-item-before");
        itemsBefore.forEach(function (cellBefore) {
            cellBefore.remove();
        })
    });
}
```

```css
body {
    user-select: none;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* img {
    pointer-events: none;
} */

.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto;
    gap: 10px;
    /* background-color: #2196F3; */
    padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container>div {
    /* background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8); */
    /* border: 1px solid black; */
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.div-point {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 10%;
}

#points {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
    /* background-color: #219; */
}

#points>div {
    /* background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8); */
    /* border: 1px solid black; */
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
}

#game {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 75px);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 75px);
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 10px;
    /* background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; */
    /* background-color: #2196F3; */
    /* padding: 10px; */
}

#game>div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 8px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body onload="start();">
    <div class="grid-container">
        <div id="points">
            <div class="div-point" id="circle">test text</div>
            <div class="div-point" id="cross">test text</div>
        </div>
        <div id="game">
            <div class="game-cell" id="cell-1"></div>
            <div class="game-cell" id="cell-2"></div>
            <div class="game-cell" id="cell-3"></div>
            <div class="game-cell" id="cell-4"></div>
            <div class="game-cell" id="cell-5"></div>
            <div class="game-cell" id="cell-6"></div>
            <div class="game-cell" id="cell-7"></div>
            <div class="game-cell" id="cell-8"></div>
            <div class="game-cell" id="cell-9"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Lo siento, no se añadir imagenes al snippet para visualizarlo